# Is there any object browser in Elpy?

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

My working environment:

```
Emacs version: 26.3
OS: Windows 10 (64 bits)
Python version: 3.8.3 (64 bits)
```

I've installed **elpy** from Melpa on Emacs. In order to navigate in my code I use C-c C-o to view the list of defined classes, functions and methods while developping Python applications. Yet, it seems that global variables and class attributes are not shown. I want to know whether it is possible to have in Emacs, some object browser allowing to view everything in the current open project? I mean The kind of tree like/hierarchical view that we can have (often as a sidebar) with Eclipse, Netbeans, Sublim, etc. showing everything: folders, classes, methods, variables, attributes.

For navigating in different folders I use Dired which does the job. So the main two things that I'm currently trying to achieve (if possible in Emacs) are:

- To have an Object browser with the characteristics that I just described above.
- When I click on an element in object browser, being able to find the very same position of the cursor before clicking on that element instead of doing C-N or C-P in order to find the previous position before continuing. Without an object browser, in the code, currently I can partially achive this with `M-.` and `M-*` while the cursor is on an identifier. But even according to the online documentation, this does not always work.